# AngularJS custom action on ngResource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource, ngresource

Confused on how to send custom parameters to a method.   I've done this:

```js
.factory('OrdersFactory', ['$resource', 'baseUrl', function ($resource, baseUrl) {
    var actionUrl = baseUrl + 'orders/';

    return $resource(actionUrl + ':id', {
         id: '@id'
    }, {
        visual: {
            method: 'GET',
            url: actionUrl + 'visualOrders/:completed/:date',
            responseType: 'json'
        }
    }
}]);
```

So my default query() gets all my orders, but now I want another method called `visual` where I specify a `completed` and a `month` parameter, and then it calls the URL indicated.

In my controller, I've imported the OrdersFactory and am using it just fine, but can't get the syntax right to call this `visual` query.

I'm wanting to do something like

```js
$completed = OrdersFactory.visual(true, '2013-08-01');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular needs to know how your params map to your url templating. One way is to pass your params as an object (i.e, key : value)

```
$completed = OrdersFactory.visual({completed: true, date: '2013-08-01'});
```